# How can I run a Linux command in Java on windows 7 platform?

Tags: java, linux

I need to execute a Linux command in my Java program. I am using  windows 7 OS. Can anyone give me a simple syntax to solve this.

Comment: be a little more clear on what you want to achieve, you want to run a (linux) command in windows, do you know if there is a program in windows (commandline or otherwise) which does the same task.. if so then @user2411994 has the answer on how to run it.

Answer (score 4):

A `Linux` command has to be executed on `linux` platform. Why would you execute it on `windows 7`?
It doesn't make any sense. The simple answer is you can't run it on `windows 7`. But you can run windows commands on `windows 7` using `java`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a Linux command, you usually need a Linux OS, not a Windows one :-)

However, there are tools like [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) which can give you a lot of the UNIXy tools under Windows. I prefer the latter myself due to the more open licensing (CygWin has some restrictions which make it unsuitable for my purposes).

Once you know *which* commands you want to run, it's a matter of looking into the Java [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and/or [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) classes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer isn't simple.  But lets start making a simple distinction

### Windows and Linux are two different Operating Systems

This entails many things.  Specifically in your case, it means that different set of programs and command will be available out of the box for each.  So, it is very likely that out of the box, the command (or program) that you are trying to run is not available on Windows.

Another important point to make is

### Command line "commands" are at times programs, and at times command of the shell you are using

A [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29) is a program that lets you interface with your operating system and with other programs in your computer.  Specifically, a "command line" shell, is the kind of shell that you run purely based on text.  You can input certain "commands" that will then execute something.  Usually, these are other programs.  For example, in linux, some of these programs commonly used are:

1. ls
2. cat
3. ps
4. find
5. grep

These are actually compiled programs.  They are usually included in Linux out of the box.  Many of these are available to be installed on Windows with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  Cygwin provides a 'linux-like' environment, by providing you access to these programs usually found on Linux, but compiled and prepared to work on Windows.

Other 'commands' like 'cd', are actually commands of the shell, as they act state-fully on the current environment (for example, 'cd' changes your current directory being used by the shell).

### What you need to do

So, what you need to find out is if the command you want to execute is actually a compiled program, and download/install Cygwin, and run your program with an absolute PATH to run the Cygwin program.
Or, if it is a 'shell command', then [find out which shell you are using](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-what-shell-im-using.html), download and install that shell with Cygwin, and run that shell with a parameter being sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("linux command");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";

while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
```

Now you've got the command as line.. If you want to make changes you can do that..